# Can you change Multiple Properties with select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, helper

I'm using the following select helper:

```
f.select(:page_color, Orders::PAYMENT_TYPES ,:prompt => "Select a Box")
```

is it possible to change multiple columns with one selection? Say I want to change :page_color and :pay_method with the selection of "Check". Is this possible?

```
     PAYMENT_TYPES = [
    #  Displayed       stored in db
    [ "Check",          "check" ],
    [ "Credit card",    "cc" ],
    [ "Purchase order", "po" ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the cleanest thing would be to write a virtual attribute:

```
def paymethod=(value)
  mapping = {
    'check' => 'red',
    'cc' => 'green',
    ...
  }

  self.page_color = mapping(value)
  super
end
```